# How do I convert SVG xml to BPMN2.0 xml

Tags: xml, svg

```
How do i convert this sample SVG to BPMN xml?

<svg height="100%" width="100%" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><desc>Created with Raphaël</desc>
    <defs></defs>
    <circle stroke-width="5" font-size="91px" style="font-size: 91px;" stroke="#000000" fill="#00ff00" r="20" cy="88" cx="107"></circle>
    <circle stroke-width="5" font-size="92px" style="font-size: 92px;" stroke="#000000" fill="#ff0000" r="20" cy="88" cx="271"></circle>
    <path stroke-width="5" d="M128,88C189,88,189,88,250,88" stroke="#ffffff" fill="none"></path>
    <path d="M128,88C189,88,189,88,250,88" stroke="#000000" fill="none"></path>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 4):

BPMN XML is an XML schema for representing the semantics of a business process, which can be mapped to a graphical visualization.  SVG represents "ink" on a drawing surface and contains no semantic information beyond where the ink goes.

In your example XML you have a couple of circles and two paths... how would a converter know what particular BPMN semantic construct is represented by that ink?  This task is reminescent of OCR but much more complex, as text is basically a one-dimensional stream of symbols but a drawing is two-dimensional.

I doubt you'll find anything that can do this.  Maybe if you explained what you're really trying to accomplish...?

Answer (score 0):

http://pi.informatik.uni-siegen.de/qudimo/bpmn/transformation/

This tool converts svg json models to bpmn 2 emf metamodel models. Which are compliant with the standard BPMN 2 serialization

Answer (score 0):

The BPMN Sketch Miner https://www.bpmn-sketch-miner.ai/ tool converts textual descriptions of process models to their visual representation both in SVG and BPMN/XML.